# Should I use bloc for the firebase authentication in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, bloc

I am working on a flutter mobile app and I am wondering if I will need the bloc state management for the authentication.
So this is the scenario of the app.
The initial screen is login and registration form
when the user login the home page will appear
when the user logout, the  login and registration form will appear and so on.

I need to know if the bloc is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use BLoC.

BLoC is one of many possibilities for state management in Flutter. The decision, which state management to choose, is independent of you use Firebase Authentication or not.

There is also

- getX https://pub.dev/packages/get
- Riverpod https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod

and many others.

Firebase authentication works with all of them. Also, you don't need any additional library to use Firebase Authentication.

Comment: When you user firebase authentication what state management pattern do you use? or you don't use state management for authentication

Comment: It does not matter. You can use any of the patterns or none. I would suggest first deciding on a state management solution, and then use it throughout your app.